# How not to break backwards compatibility with Python pickled objects

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, pickle, pybind11

I have a library in Python that I am writing which has part of the code in C++ (we connect via pybind11). This is an ML library and there are models which are expensive to retrain. Therefore objects should persist ideally once they are trained via pickling. However, I would like to keep developing the library. What is the best way of ensuring that any user of it will be able keep using pickled objects? What if the user wants to simultaneously be able to use their pickled files while allowing for any new models that they train to get all of the new features? Is there some solution akin to tagging in github but you can dynamically choose which version of the library to use?